# Error while loadagent in Java virtualmachine

Tags: java

I face the below error while loading agent in virtual machine.
Can any one help why this error occur?

Agent Code

```
    VirtualMachine localVirtualMachine = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
    localVirtualMachine.loadAgent(agentPath);       
    localVirtualMachine.detach();


Agent:
    static {
          try {
              java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
                      new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
                          public Object run() {                       
                              System.loadLibrary("JavaAccessBridge-64");
                              return null;
                          }
                      });
          } catch (Throwable e) {
              System.out.println("Exception ");
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("Exception ");

          }
            }
```

> C:\Users\mahendra>java -jar C:\Users\mahendra\Desktop\SwingSet2.jar
>   Exception in thread "Attach Listener" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Native Lib rary C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\JavaAccessBridge-64.dll already load ed in
>   another classloader
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>           at Test.TestBridge$1.run(TestBridge.java:5857)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at Test.TestBridge.(TestBridge.java:5848)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Sou
>   rce)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(Unknown
>   Source) Agent failed to start!

Comment: The message seems pretty clear: "Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\JavaAccessBridge-64.dll **already loaded** in another classloader" ... could it be that this code runs more than once?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The Java swingset2.jar already using this dll. But the Java virtualmachine provide functionality to attach dll to same jvm.